# Why are buttons when not using wxSmith flat?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxWidgets. I'm using Code::Blocks (MSW compiler), version wxWidgets-3.0.2 on Windows 7.

I started learning this, but I got stuck when I found out that I couldn't develop a good looking wxButton when I write the codes myself without using wxSmith.

All I get as output are flat wxButtons and toolbars that look like buttons. I thaught it was my fault, then I created a little frame with wxButton in it, then compiled. The output suits my taste.

I copied the exact code for this little frame and created another project file without wxSmith and I pasted them in their corresponding file. When I compile this same code, all I get is a flat wxButton.

If I hover the mouse over it, it won't turn blue as it does in wxSmith compiled code. I also noticed that anything, e.g, toolBars that is likely to be clickable, will look flat, but not menus.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the sizers correctly? Also you might want to post your code

Comment: Another thing to check might be if you have event tables in place such as wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE( YourFrame, wxFrame ) 
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to add the manifest to your application. The manifest is the thing that describes your application needs to system: what visual style you want to use, which OS are your app compatible with, etc.

The most simple way to do it with wxWidgets is to add a resource file (*.rc) to your project (or if you already have one then edit the one you have) and put this line of code there:

```
#include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
```

You may need to change the path to wx.rc file depending on your project settings. File location is:

> <wxWidgets directory>\include\wx\msw\wx.rc

wx.rc will include correct manifest based on your build type:

> x86 -> "wx/msw/wx.manifest"
>
> x64 -> "wx/msw/amd64.manifest"
>
> ia64 -> "wx/msw/ia64.manifest"

If you don't want to use wxWidgets default manifest files, then you need to:

1. create a file name your_app_name.exe.manifest (or your_dll_name.dll.manifest) and fill it manually (you can find description of application manifests and an example here: [MSDN: Application Manifests (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx);
2. place this manifest file in the folder with your executable file (just to be clear, if your app name is MyCoolApp.exe, then manifest must be named MyCoolApp.exe.manifest) or embed manifest into executable with *mt.exe* tool (mt.exe is shipped with Visual Studio, you can find the tutorial on how to use it to work with manifests here: [MSDN: How to: Embed a Manifest Inside a C/C++ Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx).